# Return DataTable from Entity Query

Tags: linq, entity-framework, datatable

I have this code:

```
public IList<T_LOGO> Get_All_Obj()
        {
            try
            {
                IList<T_LOGO> LesListe;
                using (Soft8Exp_ClientEntities oEntite_T = new Soft8Exp_ClientEntities())
                {
                    var query = from o in oEntite_T.T_LOGO select o;
                    LesListe = query.ToList();
                }
                return LesListe;
            }
            catch (Exception excThrown)
            {
                throw new Exception("Err_02", excThrown);
            }
        }
```

How can I return a DataTable instead?

```
public DataTable Get_All_Obj_DataTable()
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable TheTable = new DataTable("sd");
                using (Soft8Exp_ClientEntities oEntite_T = new Soft8Exp_ClientEntities())
                {
                    var query = from o in oEntite_T.T_LOGO select o;
                    IDbCommand cmd = Soft8Exp_ClientEntities.GetCommand(query as IQueryable); // ERROR GetCommand Not Found
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    adapter.SelectCommand = (SqlCommand)cmd;

                }
                return TheTable;
            }
            catch (Exception excThrown)
            {
                throw new Exception("Err_02", excThrown);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why do you want a DataTable? Typically, a strongly typed list is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var query = (ObjectQuery<T_LOGO>)(from o in oEntite_T.T_LOGO select o);
Var command = new SqlCommand(query.ToTraceString(),
                             ((EntityConnection)oEntite_T.Connection).StoreConnection);
```